# Angular Inject custom tag in innerHTML

Tags: html, angular

Text with custom tag to inject inside innerHtml:

`const test = '<FREEZE> the image. Then try again.'
<td [innerHtml]="test | htmlEscape"></td>`

I am using a custom pipe to disable Angular's built-in sanitization for the provided value.

custom-pipe.ts

```
@Pipe({
name: 'htmlEscape'
})
export class HtmlEscapePipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

transform(content: string): SafeHtml {
    if (!content) {
        return null;
    }

    const t = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
    return t;
}
}
```

Unfortunately `<FREEZE>` tag inside the string is stripped out. Any suggestions would be appreciate it.

Comment: Your pipe works, I tested it but I think that because <freeze> isn't an existing HTML tag, the DomSanitizer strips out that tag even if you use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()`

Comment: @tsiro I see it works fine for me, it is displayed as *<freeze> the image. Then try again.</freeze>*. is that expected ?